# Writing jQuery functions that allow chaining

Tags: jquery

I want to write some code that allows me to replace jQuery's animate function with one that does different things, but still allows me to call a secondary function on completion.

At the moment, I'm writing lots of code like this;

```
if (cssTransitions) {
   $("#content_box").css("height",0);

   window.setTimeout(function() {
       secondFunction(); 
   }, 600);
} else {
    $("#content_box").animate({
        height:0
    }, 600, function() {                
        secondFunction();
    });
}
```

I'd much rather write a function that looks like this:

```
function slideUpContent(object) {
    if (cssTransitions) {
         object.css("height",0);
         // Not sure how I get a callback here
    } else {
        $("#content_box").animate({
            height:0
        }, 600, function() {
        });
    }
}
```

That I could use like this:

```
slideUpContent("#content_box", function(){
    secondFunction();
});
```

But I'm not sure how to get the functionality I need - namely a way to run another function once my one has completed.

Can anyone help my rather addled brain?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's queue function: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is called a *callback*.

It is simple enough to implement.  Just pass the anonymous function (or other function) as a parameter, then call the variable passed in by appending brackets `callback()` (obviously checking to see if it is a valid function first).

```
function slideUpContent(object, callback) {
    if (cssTransitions) {
         object.css("height",0);
         // Perform callback if set
         if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
             callback();
         }
    } else {
        $("#content_box").animate({
            height:0
        }, 600, callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really obvious now I see it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, one question – does this work even if no callback is specified?

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw, should do. The use of callback passing to `animate()` should be fine, depends what it wants as a default.

Answer (score 1):

Chaining usually means returning this so you can do

```
$("selector").function1().function2();
```

For your example, you just need

```
function1(param1, f) {
    // do stuff
    f();
 }
```

then call it with

```
function1("parameter", function2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had recently created a sequence opening animation for a website. I found this website to be a good source of information. The part that might be helpful for you is the section titled, "Creating a sequence of animations".

http://www.elated.com/articles/super-easy-animated-effects-with-jquery/